# ReferenceError: twitterFetcher is not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm getting "ReferenceError: twitterFetcher is not defined" using this code:

```
<div id="example1" class="left"></div>
<div id="example2" class="left"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bigmouthinc.com/wp-content/themes/bmi/js/twitterFetcher_min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bigmouthinc.com/wp-content/themes/bmi/js/exampleUsage.js"></script></div>
```

The [site is in WordPress](http://www.bigmouthinc.com/). The code itself works when I remove it from WordPress so there must be something in WP that is messing with it. I've tried delaying the loading of the scripts (using 'defer' and document.ready) but I still get the error.

Any suggestions?

Here is the [plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher) and [here it is on CodePen](https://codepen.io/jasonmayes/pen/Ioype)

Comment: Can you reproduce this in codepen/jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jason Mayes was kind enough to fix my issue by posting a version of TwitterFetcher without the extra AMD checks: https://jsfiddle.net/jfqhmv0b/

```
/*********************************************************************
*  #### Twitter Post Fetcher v18.0.3 - no checks ####
*  Coded by Jason Mayes 2015. A present to all the developers out there.
*  www.jasonmayes.com
*  Please keep this disclaimer with my code if you use it. Thanks. :-)
*  Got feedback or questions, ask here:
*  http://www.jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/
*  Github: https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher
*  Updates will be posted to this site.
*********************************************************************/
var twitterFetcher=(function(){var domNode='';var maxTweets=20;var parseLinks=true;var queue=[];var inProgress=false;var printTime=true;var printUser=true;var formatterFunction=null;var supportsClassName=true;var showRts=true;var customCallbackFunction=null;var showInteractionLinks=true;var showImages=false;var useEmoji=false;var targetBlank=true;var lang='en';var permalinks=true;var dataOnly=false;var script=null;var scriptAdded=false;function handleTweets(tweets){if(customCallbackFunction===null){var x=tweets.length;var n=0;var element=document.getElementById(domNode);var html='<ul>';while(n<x){html+='<li>'+tweets[n]+'</li>';n++;}
html+='</ul>';element.innerHTML=html;}else{customCallbackFunction(tweets);}}
function strip(data){return data.replace(/<b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/b>/gi,function(a,s){return s;}).replace(/class="(?!(tco-hidden|tco-display|tco-ellipsis))+.*?"|data-query-source=".*?"|dir=".*?"|rel=".*?"/gi,'');}
function targetLinksToNewWindow(el){var links=el.getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=links.length-1;i>=0;i--){links[i].setAttribute('target','_blank');links[i].setAttribute('rel','noopener');}}
function getElementsByClassName(node,classname){var a=[];var regex=new RegExp('(^| )'+classname+'( |$)');var elems=node.getElementsByTagName('*');for(var i=0,j=elems.length;i<j;i++){if(regex.test(elems[i].className)){a.push(elems[i]);}}
return a;}
function extractImagesUrl(image_data){if(image_data!==undefined&&image_data.innerHTML.indexOf('data-image')>=0){var data_src=image_data.innerHTML.match(/data-image=\"([A-z0-9]+:\/\/[A-z0-9]+\.[A-z0-9]+\.[A-z0-9]+\/[A-z0-9]+\/[A-z0-9\-]+)\"/ig);for(var i=0;i<data_src.length;i++){data_src[i]=data_src[i].match(/data-image=\"([A-z0-9]+:\/\/[A-z0-9]+\.[A-z0-9]+\.[A-z0-9]+\/[A-z0-9]+\/[A-z0-9\-]+)\"/i)[1];data_src[i]=decodeURIComponent(data_src[i])+'.jpg';}
return data_src;}}
var twitterFetcher={fetch:function(config){if(config.maxTweets===undefined){config.maxTweets=20;}
if(config.enableLinks===undefined){config.enableLinks=true;}
if(config.showUser===undefined){config.showUser=true;}
if(config.showTime===undefined){config.showTime=true;}
if(config.dateFunction===undefined){config.dateFunction='default';}
if(config.showRetweet===undefined){config.showRetweet=true;}
if(config.customCallback===undefined){config.customCallback=null;}
if(config.showInteraction===undefined){config.showInteraction=true;}
if(config.showImages===undefined){config.showImages=false;}
if(config.useEmoji===undefined){config.useEmoji=false;}
if(config.linksInNewWindow===undefined){config.linksInNewWindow=true;}
if(config.showPermalinks===undefined){config.showPermalinks=true;}
if(config.dataOnly===undefined){config.dataOnly=false;}
if(inProgress){queue.push(config);}else{inProgress=true;domNode=config.domId;maxTweets=config.maxTweets;parseLinks=config.enableLinks;printUser=config.showUser;printTime=config.showTime;showRts=config.showRetweet;formatterFunction=config.dateFunction;customCallbackFunction=config.customCallback;showInteractionLinks=config.showInteraction;showImages=config.showImages;useEmoji=config.useEmoji;targetBlank=config.linksInNewWindow;permalinks=config.showPermalinks;dataOnly=config.dataOnly;var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];if(script!==null){head.removeChild(script);}
script=document.createElement('script');script.type='text/javascript';if(config.list!==undefined){script.src='https://syndication.twitter.com/timeline/list?'+'callback=__twttrf.callback&dnt=false&list_slug='+
config.list.listSlug+'&screen_name='+config.list.screenName+'&suppress_response_codes=true&lang='+(config.lang||lang)+'&rnd='+Math.random();}else if(config.profile!==undefined){script.src='https://syndication.twitter.com/timeline/profile?'+'callback=__twttrf.callback&dnt=false'+'&screen_name='+config.profile.screenName+'&suppress_response_codes=true&lang='+(config.lang||lang)+'&rnd='+Math.random();}else if(config.likes!==undefined){script.src='https://syndication.twitter.com/timeline/likes?'+'callback=__twttrf.callback&dnt=false'+'&screen_name='+config.likes.screenName+'&suppress_response_codes=true&lang='+(config.lang||lang)+'&rnd='+Math.random();}else{script.src='https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/'+
config.id+'?&lang='+(config.lang||lang)+'&callback=__twttrf.callback&'+'suppress_response_codes=true&rnd='+Math.random();}
head.appendChild(script);}},callback:function(data){if(data===undefined||data.body===undefined){inProgress=false;if(queue.length>0){twitterFetcher.fetch(queue[0]);queue.splice(0,1);}
return;}
if(!useEmoji){data.body=data.body.replace(/(<img[^c]*class="Emoji[^>]*>)|(<img[^c]*class="u-block[^>]*>)/g,'');}
if(!showImages){data.body=data.body.replace(/(<img[^c]*class="NaturalImage-image[^>]*>|(<img[^c]*class="CroppedImage-image[^>]*>))/g,'');}
if(!printUser){data.body=data.body.replace(/(<img[^c]*class="Avatar"[^>]*>)/g,'');}
var div=document.createElement('div');div.innerHTML=data.body;if(typeof(div.getElementsByClassName)==='undefined'){supportsClassName=false;}
function swapDataSrc(element){var avatarImg=element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];if(avatarImg){avatarImg.src=avatarImg.getAttribute('data-src-2x');}else{var screenName=element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href').split('twitter.com/')[1];var img=document.createElement('img');img.setAttribute('src','https://twitter.com/'+screenName+'/profile_image?size=bigger');element.prepend(img);}
return element;}
var tweets=[];var authors=[];var times=[];var images=[];var rts=[];var tids=[];var permalinksURL=[];var x=0;if(supportsClassName){var tmp=div.getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet');while(x<tmp.length){if(tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet-retweetCredit').length>0){rts.push(true);}else{rts.push(false);}
if(!rts[x]||rts[x]&&showRts){tweets.push(tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet-text')[0]);tids.push(tmp[x].getAttribute('data-tweet-id'));if(printUser){authors.push(swapDataSrc(tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet-author')[0]));}
times.push(tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('dt-updated')[0]);permalinksURL.push(tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet-timestamp')[0]);if(tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet-media')[0]!==undefined){images.push(tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet-media')[0]);}else{images.push(undefined);}}
x++;}}else{var tmp=getElementsByClassName(div,'timeline-Tweet');while(x<tmp.length){if(getElementsByClassName(tmp[x],'timeline-Tweet-retweetCredit').length>0){rts.push(true);}else{rts.push(false);}
if(!rts[x]||rts[x]&&showRts){tweets.push(getElementsByClassName(tmp[x],'timeline-Tweet-text')[0]);tids.push(tmp[x].getAttribute('data-tweet-id'));if(printUser){authors.push(swapDataSrc(getElementsByClassName(tmp[x],'timeline-Tweet-author')[0]));}
times.push(getElementsByClassName(tmp[x],'dt-updated')[0]);permalinksURL.push(getElementsByClassName(tmp[x],'timeline-Tweet-timestamp')[0]);if(getElementsByClassName(tmp[x],'timeline-Tweet-media')[0]!==undefined){images.push(getElementsByClassName(tmp[x],'timeline-Tweet-media')[0]);}else{images.push(undefined);}}
x++;}}
if(tweets.length>maxTweets){tweets.splice(maxTweets,(tweets.length-maxTweets));authors.splice(maxTweets,(authors.length-maxTweets));times.splice(maxTweets,(times.length-maxTweets));rts.splice(maxTweets,(rts.length-maxTweets));images.splice(maxTweets,(images.length-maxTweets));permalinksURL.splice(maxTweets,(permalinksURL.length-maxTweets));}
var arrayTweets=[];var x=tweets.length;var n=0;if(dataOnly){while(n<x){arrayTweets.push({tweet:tweets[n].innerHTML,author:authors[n]?authors[n].innerHTML:'Unknown Author',author_data:{profile_url:authors[n]?authors[n].querySelector('[data-scribe="element:user_link"]').href:null,profile_image:authors[n]?'https://twitter.com/'+authors[n].querySelector('[data-scribe="element:screen_name"]').title.split('@')[1]+'/profile_image?size=bigger':null,profile_image_2x:authors[n]?'https://twitter.com/'+authors[n].querySelector('[data-scribe="element:screen_name"]').title.split('@')[1]+'/profile_image?size=original':null,screen_name:authors[n]?authors[n].querySelector('[data-scribe="element:screen_name"]').title:null,name:authors[n]?authors[n].querySelector('[data-scribe="element:name"]').title:null},time:times[n].textContent,timestamp:times[n].getAttribute('datetime').replace('+0000','Z').replace(/([\+\-])(\d\d)(\d\d)/,'$1$2:$3'),image:(extractImagesUrl(images[n])?extractImagesUrl(images[n])[0]:undefined),images:extractImagesUrl(images[n]),rt:rts[n],tid:tids[n],permalinkURL:(permalinksURL[n]===undefined)?'':permalinksURL[n].href});n++;}}else{while(n<x){if(typeof(formatterFunction)!=='string'){var datetimeText=times[n].getAttribute('datetime');var newDate=new Date(times[n].getAttribute('datetime').replace(/-/g,'/').replace('T',' ').split('+')[0]);var dateString=formatterFunction(newDate,datetimeText);times[n].setAttribute('aria-label',dateString);if(tweets[n].textContent){if(supportsClassName){times[n].textContent=dateString;}else{var h=document.createElement('p');var t=document.createTextNode(dateString);h.appendChild(t);h.setAttribute('aria-label',dateString);times[n]=h;}}else{times[n].textContent=dateString;}}
var op='';if(parseLinks){if(targetBlank){targetLinksToNewWindow(tweets[n]);if(printUser){targetLinksToNewWindow(authors[n]);}}
if(printUser){op+='<div class="user">'+strip(authors[n].innerHTML)+'</div>';}
op+='<p class="tweet">'+strip(tweets[n].innerHTML)+'</p>';if(printTime){if(permalinks){op+='<p class="timePosted"><a href="'+permalinksURL[n]+'">'+times[n].getAttribute('aria-label')+'</a></p>';}else{op+='<p class="timePosted">'+
times[n].getAttribute('aria-label')+'</p>';}}}else{if(tweets[n].textContent){if(printUser){op+='<p class="user">'+authors[n].textContent+'</p>';}
op+='<p class="tweet">'+tweets[n].textContent+'</p>';if(printTime){op+='<p class="timePosted">'+times[n].textContent+'</p>';}}else{if(printUser){op+='<p class="user">'+authors[n].textContent+'</p>';}
op+='<p class="tweet">'+tweets[n].textContent+'</p>';if(printTime){op+='<p class="timePosted">'+times[n].textContent+'</p>';}}}
if(showInteractionLinks){op+='<p class="interact"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/'+'tweet?in_reply_to='+tids[n]+'" class="twitter_reply_icon"'+
(targetBlank?' target="_blank" rel="noopener">':'>')+'Reply</a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?'+'tweet_id='+tids[n]+'" class="twitter_retweet_icon"'+
(targetBlank?' target="_blank" rel="noopener">':'>')+'Retweet</a>'+'<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id='+
tids[n]+'" class="twitter_fav_icon"'+
(targetBlank?' target="_blank" rel="noopener">':'>')+'Favorite</a></p>';}
if(showImages&&images[n]!==undefined&&extractImagesUrl(images[n])!==undefined){var extractedImages=extractImagesUrl(images[n]);for(var i=0;i<extractedImages.length;i++){op+='<div class="media">'+'<img src="'+extractedImages[i]+'" alt="Image from tweet" />'+'</div>';}}
if(showImages){arrayTweets.push(op);}else if(!showImages&&tweets[n].textContent.length){arrayTweets.push(op);}
n++;}}
handleTweets(arrayTweets);inProgress=false;if(queue.length>0){twitterFetcher.fetch(queue[0]);queue.splice(0,1);}}};window.__twttrf=twitterFetcher;window.twitterFetcher=twitterFetcher;return twitterFetcher;})();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Fix

Use AMD in your code, or disable Dojo's AMD, or remove the AMD / CommonJS compatibility of TwitterFetcher (see below).

#### Explanation

TwitterFetcher spot if there's AMD or node environment :

```
(function(root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        factory();
    }
}(this, function() { ...
```

In your website, you're using Dojo, which uses AMD (if you type `define.amd`, you get `{vendor: "dojotoolkit.org"}`)

So, TwitterFetcher detects this, and is exposed on `window` later than you think (when it's loaded by AMD).

That's probably why it works outside of your Wordpress, because you're out of an AMD environment.

Comment: @webguy I'm not a specialist, but here's a resource I found that might help : https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/ Or just cut the AMD lookup part of TwitterFetcher (the code mentioned on my answer) for now